# jQuery Audio Button

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I've got a problem with a button playing sound files.

There are two buttons, one is enabling the sound-button and the other one plays the sound when clicked. Basically, only buttons with the class "enabled" play sounds, but when I set the class of a button to enabled and then click it, nothing happens.

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/agesem/2/)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://cd.textfiles.com/10000soundssongs/WAV/DOORBELL.WAV');

    $('.enabled').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
});
});
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#enabler').click(function() {
  $('.disabled').attr('class','enabled');
  $('.enabled').text('Play (enabled)');
});
});
</script>
<style>
.enabled{color:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class="disabled">Play</button>
<button id="enabler">Make Play-Button work</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is, as always, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you initiate the `click` event listener for the `.enabled` selector, there are no elements with the class of `enabled` that exist to bind the function to. You need to bind the event listener to a parent element that exists so that when the button is clicked it will run the function.

You need to change

```
$('.enabled').click(function() {
    audioElement.play();
});
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.enabled', function() {
    audioElement.play();
});
```

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agesem/5/edit) showing this.

Comment: I don't quite get your point but I think you are right.
Could you edit the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/agesem/2/edit) your way?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="enabler">Make Play-Button work</button>
```

you have error at this line its enabler and its need to be enabled 
:-)

Comment: Hmm, not really actually. That button is the enabler for the sound-button (sets the sound-buttons's class to .enabled) `<button id="enabler">` --> `$('#enabler').click(function() {`